# Is there any mail list frontend that provides forum like interface?

Tags: email

I would like to have my mail lists presented like a forum (let's say phpBB), instead of having to browse through this unorganized pile of data: http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/ranger-users/

Is there any app that can do that? Google Groups is a good example of such an interface, but it's only available for internal mailing lists.

Comment: Will http://www.mail-archive.com/ fit your requirements?

Comment: No, I dont need a search engine, I would like different interface.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen gmane.org, if that's close enough. (Its also built from open source components, so you could run a private internal one if you need to). Otherwise, you *could* use Google Groups, even if just by subscribing it to your existing mailing list.

Comment: What do you mean about google groups ? How could I use it with external mail lists ? Lets say the one I mentioned above.